# GROUP BY query not showing empty categories

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I've got the following

```
SELECT
        help_categories.helpCatId,
        help_categories.helpCatName,
        help_categories.helpCatSlug,
        COUNT(help_articles.helpArtCatId)
FROM
        help_categories
            JOIN
                help_articles
                    ON help_categories.helpCatId = help_articles.helpArtCatId
WHERE 
        help_categories.helpCatActive = 1
    AND
        help_articles.helpArtActive = 1
GROUP BY
        help_articles.helpArtCatId
ORDER BY
        help_categories.helpCatId ASC
```

This query selects all the help categories from the database, and counts all the articles in it.

**The problem:** when a category has 0 articles, it's not fetched.

Is this a good query, or does anyone knows a better way to do this. So I want ALL the categories + the number of articles in every category (even if a category has 0 articles I still want to fetch the category data from the database).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +upvote to this question since everyone else gave an answer which doesn't relate directly to the problem :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause undoes the effort of a `LEFT JOIN` with null values: `... AND help_articles.helpArtActive = 1`. That needs an "OR NULL":

Should be:

```
WHERE 
        help_categories.helpCatActive = 1
    AND
        (help_articles.helpArtActive = 1
         OR
         help_articles.helpArtActive IS NULL
         )
```

Edit, based on comments:

Additionally, the `GROUP BY help_articles.helpArtCatId` is going to put `help_articles.helpArtCatId` NULLs togther. May want to `GROUP BY help_categories.helpCatId` instead.

Comment: it's almost working... I have 7 categories currently, and only the first 3 have articles in it. With your solution, the 4th category is also shown (with the message "no articles found"), but the last 3 categories are not fetched. (I changed JOIN to LEFT JOIN ofc). They all are active (helpCatActive = 1).

Comment: That's because of `GROUP BY help_articles.helpArtCatId` putting the NULLs together. You probably want to do `GROUP BY help_categories.helpCatId` instead. (And that may then require additional changes to the query.)

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much aneroid!

Answer (score 0):

You want a [left join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html). This allows you to retrieve all rows from the "left" side of the query, regardless of whether there are matches on the "right" side of the query.

Comment: Thanks Neville, but it gives me exact the same result. Can you give me a small hint how to change my query. If I just change "JOIN" to "LEFT JOIN", it doens't change the output... I think I also have to change the WHERE clausule...

Comment: If you post a SQLFiddle, with sample data, you'll probably get an answer in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Comment: LEFT JOIN gives me exact the same result. I know the solution is with the LEFT JOIN though... :/